# What is the difference between "Set" and "Add" for ObjectCache?

Tags: asp.net, caching

From the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **Add(CacheItem, CacheItemPolicy)** : When overridden in a derived class, *tries to* insert a cache entry into the cache as a CacheItem instance, and adds details about how the entry should be evicted. [[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780569%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

-

> **Set(CacheItem, CacheItemPolicy)** : When overridden in a derived class, inserts the cache entry into the cache as a CacheItem instance, specifying information about how the entry will be evicted. [[2]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780578%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I see little difference in the wording (*tries to*) and signature (`set` is a sub, `add` returns a boolean), but I'm not sure which one I should use and if there is really something different between both.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The Main difference is that the `Add()` method tries to insert a cache without overwriting an existing cache entry with the  same key.

While the `Set()` method will overwrite an existing cache entry having the same key. [ However If the key for an item does not exist, insertion will be done as a new cache entry ].

Above was the difference in terms of their functionality.

**Syntactical Difference:**

One significant syntactical difference is that the `Add()` method returns a Boolean which is `true` if insertion succeeded, or `false` if there is already an entry in the cache that has the same key as item.
The `Set()` method has a `void` return type.

One last point that internal implementation of `Add()` method actually calls its corresponding version of [**`AddOrGetExisting()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.addorgetexisting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
 public virtual bool Add(CacheItem item, CacheItemPolicy policy)
{
    return this.AddOrGetExisting(item, policy) == null;
}
```

Comment: Perfect concise answer on a somewhat obscure pair of methods.  This is why I love SO you probably saved me an hour or searching or testing.

Comment: It seems that Add method will not create a cache item if another cache item with same key exists!